# How to focus an element after re-render with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, autofocus

In my web-app, a user can save the current record by pressing `enter`.
A message is then shown showing "record successfully saved".

Since the blinking cursor in one of the input boxes detracts from the "the record is now saved" impression, I'd like the application to focus a particular control at this point, like a "Back" button, for example.

How can I get React to set focus to an element during a re-render? If I use a `someCreatedRef.current.focus()` command, should that be before or after the `setState` command?

I've tried everything I can find in documentation about focusing elements, and none of it works for me:

- Most articles speak to how to focus controls when a component is first mounted, but I want to do this after `setState` is called.
- Other articles speak of how to do it using references, notably `createRef` and `Ref callbacks`. I tried both and neither seem to work and I suspect that this is because those are use cases where setState is  not called, so the component is not rerendered - it's merely a button or action causing a different element to get focussed upon  the same "render"...
- There are also some articles that speak of using `autofocus`, but this seems to do nothing in my case.

Edit: Thanks to Ganesh Krishna, I could crack this. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-swartz-qvjo7?file=/src/App.js) is a code Sandbox of this solution.

Comment: You ask whether to set it before or after `setState`, it shouldn't matter as long as nothing else steals the focus. Have you tried both and neither works? As long as you have a ref to the element you want to focus, focusing should be instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If I use a someCreatedRef.current.focus() command, should that be before or after the setState command?

   There is no such order.
2. but I want to do this after setState is called.

   If you want to execute certain changes after setState is called you can do the following.

**If you are using class component:
setState method provides a callback function that can be executed after state change has been made.**

```
this.setState({
    // set the state variable 
},() => {
    // add the code to focus on particular element.
});
```

**If you are using hooks:
Just add useEffect hook and add the state variable after which is set, you want to focus, as a dependency**

```
useEffect(() => {
 // add the code to focus on particular element.
}, [stateVariable])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh Krishna. This helped me figure it out. Finally the problem was also that I was trying to focus on material ui TextFields, which need a special attribute `inputRef=...` as opposed to the usual `ref=...` I am updating my post with a codeSandBox of how it works in the end.